# How to snap data first and second level data from firebase at the same time?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to snap the key of data in the second level and the value of data in first level at the same time in order to get something like this:

```
{"jasper"}
{"526"}
 {"地理"}
```

[image: pic]

what should I do?

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by 'snap the key of data'? If you read the node with the key of 'jasper' you will have access to all of the data beneath it 'at the same time'. In your screenshot, the node containing '526' and 'Jasper' are all child nodes of a parent node so you would have access to everything in that node if the parent node is read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as is.

What I would recommend would be to store datas as you need them on the requested node. So no values for the second lvl.

Then adding a second node wich will contain the values behind the same key, and request it with the keys that the first request bring back.